# What is the behavior of a link with both preload and stylesheet in rel attribute?

Tags: html, css, asynchronous

I'm reading about approachs to load CSS stylesheets asynchronously. One common way is as below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'">
```

It works fine. But today I see a large website using following way to load the CSS (to what they said that is asynchronously):

```html
<link rel="preload stylesheet" href="style.css" as="style">
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></noscript>
```

Notice the link have both `preload` and `stylesheet` and has `as="style"` at the end. I'm curious to know if it works that way, or it will be a blocking request?

Notes:

- I already know common methods to loading the CSS asynchronously, this question is not about how to do it, I'm just ask about above method, as I don't see it is documented anywhere.
- I see common way is split preload and stylesheet into 2 links, so I'm thinking that using both of them in the same link will not work, this question is to asking for a confirmation.

Comment: have you simply tested it and see what it does?

Comment: Are you sure they don't have some JS running afterwards that does something like `link.res = link.res.replace("preload ", "")`? Could you share a link to the page wher you saw this? I'm not an expert in this area and I didn't check the specs yet, but I kind of share your doubts about how this should work.

Comment: Testing on my own, it seems that this <link> becomes render-blocking and from fast reading the specs that's what I'd also expect. If I read correctly, which I'm not sure at all, hence I don't post an answer, both links should be created, and thus you'd have a *preload* link (which is not render-blocking), **and** a *stylesheet* link (which is "potentially" render-blocking). Both links will apparently use the same network request, but the *css* link will anyway block the rendering, so *preload* becomes moot  here. But once again, I'm not 100% sure that's what happens. I'll poke around.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think it would be great to add it inside your question. Also, could you clarify from where you got the "*to what they said that is asynchronously*" bit? I can't see any comment in the source that says it's why they used this.

Comment: @Kaiido I know the people who worked to create the site, and we discuss about that technicque, they confirm there is no JS to change how those links working later. One thing for sure they believe that it make the CSS load asynchronously.

Comment: According to Noam Rosenthal's recollections (they did consequent work on this matter), "*IIRC you can have several rels and it would behave similarly to having two link elements with those rels the other attributes identical. In this and other cases this will not create a very useful outcome*"

Comment: @Kaiido the 2 links sit next to each other then one of them will blocks the main thread anyway, isn't it. If it is then we will not get the async load benifit, otherwise it will be too good to be true, as I see all the technology to load CSS asyncly today have to have JS involved (some sites have strict CSP will not allow things like inline onload event, but seem currently there is no other way that don't require JS).

Comment: Hi @tacoshy,  I just published a test suite for this question, please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: it is a blocking request.

---

Long answer:
I created a demo for this situation and below is what I observered.

### Prerequisites

Create a CSS file that take long time to load.

In below samples, it will be `/style.css` and it takes 5 seconds to load. The content is as below:

```css
* {
 color: red;
}
```

so when the CSS loaded successfully, all the text in the page will have red color.

Notes:

- All of the tests was executed locally so it take ~0 second to load the HTML only.
- All of the tests was conducted on Chrome v113, Windows 10 64bit.

### Tests:

1. Normal case:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- normal way -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>normal way</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

2. Media print + onload:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- media print then onload -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="/style.css"
      media="print"
      onload="this.onload = null;this.media='all'" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>media print then onload</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

3. Preload + onload:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- preload then onload -->
    <link
      href="/style.css"
      rel="preload"
      as="style"
      onload="this.onload = null;this.rel='stylesheet'" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>preload then onload</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

4. Preload + stylesheet on same link:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- preload + stylesheet -->
    <link
      rel="preload stylesheet"
      href="/style.css"
      as="style" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>preload + stylesheet</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Results

- Test 1: Page takes 5 seconds to load, has correct style when loaded.
- Test 2: Page load instantly, takes 5 seconds to has correct style.
  Loading icon in tab bar appears for 5 seconds.
- Test 3: Page load instantly, takes 5 seconds to has correct style.
  No loading icon.
- Test 4: Page takes 5 seconds to load, has correct style when loaded.
  (Behavior is the same with Test 1).

Answer (score 1):

Adding multiple keywords in the same `rel` attribute will create one (internal) *link* per keyword.
This means that when you do `<link rel="preload stylesheet" as="style" href="...` you will have both a non blocking *preload* link, and a potentially blocking *stylesheet* one.
So this won't work to make the style-sheet load in a non blocking way, because the `stylesheet` one will block and disable any benefit you could have had from `preload`.

It seems that you can get a non-render-blocking `<link rel="stylesheet">` by declaring it at the end of the `<body>`, though I'm not sure how "bullet-proof" this is.

```css
/* We're in <head> here */
:root { --red-500: green; }
span { color: var(--red-500); }
```

```html
<span>If the rendering is not blocked I should be green then red</span>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://app.requestly.io/delay/1000/https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css?v=e149631cb3f3">
```

Comment: Hi @Kaiido, I just published a test suite for this question, please have a look at my answer.

Comment: @Horizon yes that just confirms what I say in this answer, which is the expected behavior.